# Examining $\inf \int_0^1(x')^{2}(t)\mathrm dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I need to examine 
$$\inf \int_0^1(x')^{2}(t)\mathrm dt$$
with such conditions:

\begin{cases} x(0)=0, x(1)=1 & \\
\int_0^1x(t)dt=0 &
\end{cases}

I started with writing Euler-Lagrange equation for $F[t,x(t),x'(t)]=\int_0^1(x')^{2}(t)\mathrm dt$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}2x'(t)=0.$$

Obviously, the solution of this differential equation is $x(t)=Ct+D$. Because of the conditions from $(1)$ I assumed that $C=1, D=0$. But then, function $x(t)=t$ does not fulfill the second condition. What did I do wrong? Where should I take this second condition into account? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the Euler Lagrange equation directly as you have another constraint
$$L(x) = \int_0^1 x(t) dt = 0.$$
Instead, you need to use the Lagrangian multiplier: You want to minimize 
$$G(x) = \int_0^1 (x')^2(t) dx$$
subject to $L(x) = 0$. So by Lagrangian multiplier, there is $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ so that 
$$\nabla G = \lambda \nabla L,$$
that is, for all test functions 
$$2 \int_0^1 x'(t) \phi'(t) dt = \lambda \int_0^1 \phi(t) dt.$$
Using integration by part, we have 
$$\int_0^1 (2x''(t) + \lambda)\phi(t) dt = 0$$
for all test functions $\phi$. So 
$$x''(t) = C$$
and we can write $x(t) = at^2 + bt +c$. Using now the boundary conditions and $L(x) = 0$, we find 
$$x(t) = 3t^2 - 2t.$$
Thus the infimum of $G(x)$ is (!)
$$G(3t^2 - 2t) = \int_0^1 (6t - 2)^2 dt = 4.$$

(I am bypassing a hard question: How do I know that this is a minimum? In general the Eular-Lagrange method give us only the critical points)

Comment: Thank you very much! But I don't understand how did we bypass this hard question. I mean, why do we know that it IS a minimum?

Comment: The use of Euler-Lagrange method is what we call the "indirect method", we assume that there is a critical point and then find out $x(t)$. This method does not help us justify why the found $x(t)$ is a mnimmum. You need a "direct method" to argue that minimum does exists. In this case you need to use some functional analysis. I am not sure if that is what you are supposed to do in your class cause it's totally different stuff. I can write down a proof if you wish to. @sarnow

Comment: I think I need to show that it is a minimum. Isn't there any simple way to prove that?

Comment: I do not quite see an easy proof of that. One might rewrite the whole proof without using Euler-Lagrange equation but instead Fourier series (not completely sure if I can say something, still working on it). What courses are you taking? It is common that in a first course in variational method the "direct method" is not discussed. @sarnow

Comment: This course is called "Differential Equations" but I'm also taking functional analysis classes. Maybe you are right, but we had some "sufficient condition" theorems for E-L equation (for example, when we deal with a  convex function) and I thought that maybe in this case we'd also have something more. Thank you very much for your help :)